# Aspect Oriented Programming for Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, aop

What are some good aspect oriented programming libraries/frameworks that will run on google app engine (Java version)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) count?  I've only used it for Dependency Injection, but [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP) makes a  convincing case for using it for AOP too.

Comment: It seems to be able to insert code into methods, but can it create fields within a class?